# Java - mouselistener in Windows OS

Tags: java, operating-system, actionlistener, mouselistener

Is it possible to make an `action/mouselistener` that listens for mouse `movements/actions` in Windows (OS).

For example, the `action/mouselistener` would react when the user highlights (or hovers over) a piece of String in txt or any other file / program.

Comment: This would require a program that can get close to the OS, and so Java would not be your best tool for this. You could do it with JNA or JNI, but you're probably better off doing it all in C or C++.

Comment: You could repeated poll MouseInfo.getPointerInfo() which will give you mouse position but thats about it. Like Hovercraft Full Of Eels said, Java does not expose low level OS functions in its standard API.